# Tuning the signature size of Sphincs+

Tags: hash-signature

If I only need a small number of signatures (perhaps $2^{10}$) for the lifetime of my key pair, how would I calculate the consequent signature size?

Unfortunately managing state for an LMS or XMSS signature would be an issue, so that's not an option.

Comment: That computation is surprisingly nontrivial.